# C++ Reference invalidation

Tags: c++, events, c++11, reference

I am writing an event system for a game engine, and I need a way to 'disconnect' functions from the event (erase from std::vector) but I also require that to remove an event the developer must give a valid reference to the function they wish to disconnect.

At the moment I have a class like this:

```
template<typename ... Args>
class event{
    public:
        using delegate_type = std::function<void(Args...)>;

        void operator()(Args ... args){
            for(auto &&f : m_funcs)
                f(args...);
        }

        template<typename FunctorType>
        delegate_type &connect(FunctorType &&f){
            m_funcs.emplace_back(f);
            return m_funcs.back();
        }

        bool disconnect(delegate_type &f){
            for(auto iter = begin(m_funcs); iter != end(m_funcs); ++iter)
                if(&(*iter) == &f){ // if the dev passed a valid function
                    m_funcs.erase(iter);
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }

    private:
        std::vector<delegate_type> m_funcs;
};
```

But this of-course suffers from reference invalidation whenever the underlying vector is resized after a `disconnect` or `connect` operation.

I tried switching to an `std::list` solution rather than `std::vector` but the speed difference when iterating over the functions is detrimental enough that I can not make that switch in a release build.

Is there some way I can avoid the invalidation using a helper class or identifier instead of a straight reference?

Comment: This sounds like a job for one of the associative containers.

Comment: @T.C. at the moment I'm trying to implement an ID system

Comment: Is it intentional that one can "connect" the same `FunctorType` reference multiple times, and each results in a distinct slot in `m_funcs` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig well, if somebody wants a function to be connected multiple times, I see nothing wrong with that

Comment: A (not so great) solution is to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<delegate_type>>` and return pointers to the delegate instead of a reference. These won't be affected by `vector` reallocation.

Comment: @Praetorian would that be much more efficient than an `std::forward_list` though?

Comment: Maybe, you'll have to try it out. It gives you cache locality for the pointers themselves, but not to what those pointers are pointing at. But it should be better than a `forward_list` at least for that `disconnect` function.

Comment: Well, I tried a `std::unique_ptr<delegate_type>` approach and an `std::pair<delegate_type, id_type>` approach and the id approach won by about 30 ms in a full iteration of an event of 10000000 functions. So I am sticking with the ids for now :D

Comment: @0x499602D2 could you explain why that doesn't cause invalidation?

Comment: The ID sounds better than unnecessary dynamic allocation to me too. @0x499602D2 Even erase remove will invalidate all references to elements after the one that was erased because they get moved forward.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/signals.html). When connecting, it returns a `sigc::connection` object. You can keep it client-side and use it for disconnecting or it will disconnect automatically the slot when it is destroyed. It does not suffer from the reference invalidation problem.

Answer (score 0):

Store `weak_ptr<delegate_type>`. Remove invalid ones on each invocation (`remove_if`).  (`operator()`).  Guard agains recursive invocation somehow as an aside.

Return `shared_ptr<delegate_type>` as your token.  The external user simply `.reset()`s to unregister.  No need to `disconnect`!

Allocate with `make_shared<delegate_type>` within `connect`.

Make `connect` a `template` that perfect forwards into the `make_shared`.

Comment: Too slow for my use case, id's are still what I'm gonna use

Answer (score 0):

Use an associative container, like the std::list you were using.

But, you'll need a more complicated use of the container so you can eliminate the overhead of looping over it.
The best solution is of course just removing the need of the loop.

The most efficient way, would be to then return an iterator for the container's cell instead of the function itself.
A remove like this would avoid the search, because you'll have the iterator location already.
In associative containers the iterators don't get invalidated (But beware, it's not thread safe of course).

```
template<typename FunctorType>
        std::list<delegate_type>::iterator &connect(FunctorType &&f){
            m_funcs.emplace_back(f);
            //get the iterator for the last item
            return m_funcs.end()--;
        }

bool disconnect(std::list<delegate_type>::iterator &f){
           //direct removal
            m_funcs.erase(f);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't help, the whole point of this post was to remove the need for `std::list` because it is too slow when running over every element upon calling `operator()(Args...args)`